# Trying to Position Form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to use JavaScript to create a form and position it.  I use the following code.

```
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('action',"submit.php");

// Position form
f.setAttribute('offsetTop',offsetTop);
f.setAttribute('offsetLeft',parseInt(offsetLeft)+parseInt(imageWidth));

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
```

However, when I examine the DOM using Firebug, the position of the form is the same as if I had not use the form positioning calls at all.  That is, it is beneath the last element which is an image.

Comment: You need to use CSS layout techniques.

Comment: Why would CSS be preferable to JavaScript.  Is it because JavaScript can be, and sometimes is, disabled?  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: No. Javascript cannot position elements.  Javascript can set CSS properties that position elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('action',"submit.php");

// Position form
f.style.position = "absolute";
f.style.top = offsetTop +"px";
f.style.left = (parseInt(offsetLeft)+parseInt(imageWidth)) +"px";
```

Answer (score 1):

offsetTop and offsetLeft is not CSS property. And you need use not static position. Use "style":

```
f.style.position = "absolute";//or relative, fixed
f.style.top = offsetTop+"px";//set css top
```